# Store image to SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to save an image into SQL Server database using PHP

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImageList](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Image] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[FactID] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

and my code is:

```
$img_data = (file_get_contents($_FILES['glryimage']['tmp_name']));
$tsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.ImageList (
            FactID,
            Image) 
            VALUES
            (?, ?)";
$var = array($FactID, $img_data);

if (!sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $var)) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
} else {
}
```

and when try to insert to database get error

> SQLSTATE: IMSSP
> message: An error occurred translating string for input param 4 to UCS-2: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

Please how I can store an image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381819/14868997 also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be caused due to `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` character encoding that may not be supported by the server `bin2hex` PHP function may solve the issue, just give it a try

`$img_data = bin2hex(file_get_contents($_FILES['glryimage']['tmp_name']));`

use PHP documentation for reference.

[bin to hex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

[hex to bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php)

Comment: thanks bro, But how I can retrieve the image from database in this case, Because I' trying but doesn't working

Comment: i havent tried that but this post may help you, just go through it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662779/php-create-file-from-an-hex-string